# How to remove checkout

Tags: checkout

I want to remove checkout from the shop. I need customers to simply place the order and that would finish it. No payment at all (we send the invoice to our customers manually - we just need users place orders)

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Timur Gafforov,you issue at payment step and not other step/

Comment: Hi! what is that supposed to mean? :)

Comment: as per as my thought,It will better to  use checkout with skin payment steps at checkout.Otherwise you need to customization for pragmatically create order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For placing any order user must have to fill billing,shipping info.
But as per your requirement You can use `Purchase Order` as a payment method!

Answer (score 0):

In `System -> Config -> Payment methods` you have the option `Check/Money` order. That option is for when you get money offline from customer.